# Why do Darkweb Tor addresses change so often?

Tags: network-configuration

I've seen Dark web sites before that like to change their URL often. Often changing URL after handing out the new address to old users.

Why do they do this? Is there a specific reason URL hopping is necessary?

Answer (score 2):

no technical reason here, usually it is used to achieve three main goals:

- **audience refining** You can give the new address only to the persons you trust
- **hunting avoidance** If there're too many mentioning about your HS with it's url published, *sometimes* it can become a target to government-covered abusers, like in Russia
- **going deeper** if you're not about to make your HS for everybody - it's like a making a "New identity" switch, a links will lead to your old URL